# Set an execution order for @Scheduled methods in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations

I am making a simple application on springboot 2.2.0.RELEASE.

I have 4 classes annotated with @Component that contain a scheduled method.
Currently, the 4 methods are declared like this :

```
 @Scheduled(fixedRate = 3600000)
 protected void syncData() {
      //Do something each hour.
 }
```

I want to set an order for those methods to execute.

Something like :
Class3 first, Class1 after, etc..

How can I do that?

Comment: If it is a dependency why not call from one another ?

Comment: Or perhaps a single bean with an @Schedule, where the method calls each injected dependency in the expected order.

Comment: Yes I could do that, I am just wondering if there are any magical ways to do it with annotations.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense, if you want spring to wait until one job finished before starting another, that would go against the fixedRate that is defined.  Your best bet is to have a single @Scheduled that calls the various beans

Comment: you can use cron job in the @Schedule annotation and instead set en exact interval for each method, so that they will be executed at maybe each hour, and each hour plus one minute etc. But not so that they will get triggered when one is finished.